# how to tell if mouse is click or keyboard is press

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to check if the mouse is click or key is press.
like if i click on something i can set Timer back to zero.
or press any key, do the same.

Comment: there are onclick, onkeypress events that you can bind to using jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery, bind `keypress` and `click` events to the document:

```
$(document).on('keypress click', function(e) {
    //reset timer to 0
});
```

Take a read of the [API doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for `.on()`.

Comment: This will work..
$(document).on is what i wanted.
I'm new at java script so THANKS VERY MUCH. ^^,

Answer (score 1):

Use the keypress and click events given by jQuery library.
Your event should be linked with an element in the DOM

Reference

http://api.jquery.com/click/

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to implement both within a singular function, you can just use the submit eventlistener which covers both mouseclick and keyboard enter.